# Why doesn't these script work at the same time and how do I merge them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using two script based on my sites meta title, and im trying to get two scripts to work together. I hoped it was enough to change the functions name, but if i use twi script one will not work. Why? and also, is it better if I merge them, and how would I do that?

Script one:

```
$('document').ready(
function() {
function _title(){
var allow = document.title.search("IT Distribution - ");
if(allow>-1){
document.getElementById('tesbanner').style.display="block";
}
}
window.onload=_title;
});
```

Script two:

```
$('document').ready(
function() {
function _title2(){
var allow = document.title.search("IT Distribution - ");
if(allow>-1){
document.getElementById('navLogout2').style.display="block";
}
}
window.onload=_title2;
});
```

Comment: My first guess is that `window.onload` does not append functions, but overwrites them.

Comment: You are not calling your functions.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles That guess is a good guess. `onload` is a property, it cannot have 2 functions assigned to it. Multiple `onload` functions require the use of event, so Vanilla `addEventListener` or jQuery `on`.

Comment: Is there a specific need why you have two function doing exactly the same thing with just the one element of difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both functions into one

```
    $('document').ready(
        function() {
           var _title = function(element) {
             var allow = document.title.search("IT Distribution - ");
               if(allow>-1){
                 document.getElementById(element).style.display="block";
               }
           };
       _title('tesbanner');
       _title('navLogout2');
   });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('document').ready(
    function() {
        (function _title(){
            var allow = document.title.search("IT Distribution - ");
            if(allow>-1){
                document.getElementById('tesbanner').style.display="block";
            }
        })();
        (function _title2(){
            var allow = document.title.search("IT Distribution - ");
            if(allow>-1){
                document.getElementById('navLogout2').style.display="block";
            }
        })();
});
```